# Call RelayCommand<T> with CanExecute Parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I call a RelayCommand by passing in the CanExecute Parameter. The object is being bound as a command paramenter from the view. I have the following piece of code which says 'Delegate Func does not take 0 arguments'. Please help. The definition for OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView and IsPrintAndExportEnabled is as follows.

```
     RelayCommand m_PrintAllChartsCommand;
                public ICommand PrintAllChartsCommand
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return m_PrintAllChartsCommand ?? (m_PrintAllChartsCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                            OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView,
                            () => IsPrintAndExportEnabled() //This line there is a compiler error
                            ));
                    }
                }

private void OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView(object obj)
        {
//do something. The obj is bound as command parameter from the view.
        }

    private bool IsPrintAndExportEnabled()
    {
    //I will do some operation here and change to return true or false later
    return false;
    }
```

Here is the RelayCommand class that I am trying to call

```
namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command
{

    public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the RelayCommand class that can always execute.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   execute:
        //     The execution logic.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     If the execute argument is null.
        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the RelayCommand class.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   execute:
        //     The execution logic.
        //
        //   canExecute:
        //     The execution status logic.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   T:System.ArgumentNullException:
        //     If the execute argument is null.
        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute);

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when changes occur that affect whether the command should execute.
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        //
        // Summary:
        //     Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current
        //     state.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   parameter:
        //     Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed,
        //     this object can be set to a null reference
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   parameter:
        //     Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed,
        //     this object can be set to a null reference
        public virtual void Execute(object parameter);
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Raises the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1.CanExecuteChanged event.
        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Execute and CanExecute must have the same signature and parameters....object is missing : param => { return IsPrintAndExportEnabled(param); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me. In case if it helps anyone. First look at the RelayCommand, the way I am declaring is wrong. It should be `RelayCommand<object>` This is the complete declaration and usage.

```
   RelayCommand<object> m_PrintAllChartsCommand;
        public ICommand PrintAllChartsCommand
        {
            get
            {

                return m_PrintAllChartsCommand ?? (m_PrintAllChartsCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                    OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView, IsPrintAndExportEnabled));

            }
        }
private void OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView(object arg)
 {

 }

 private bool IsPrintAndExportEnabled(object arg)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are taking a command parameter of type T (which you are declaring as object), the RelayCommand CanExecute requires a single argument of type T and returns bool. You are passing in an anonymous function which takes no arguments and returns a bool. You can simply replace

```
() => IsPrintAndExportEnabled();
```

with

```
arg => { return IsPrintAndExportEnabled(); }
```

if you do not intend to do anything with the object passed to the CanExecute.

If you do not need a command parameter, then you do not need to declare your RelayCommand as

```
RealyCommand<object>(execute, canExecute);
```

it can simply be

```
RelayCommand(execute, canExecute);
```

where in this case the Execute would take no arguments and return void and the CanExecute would take no arguments and return a bool.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this. Notice that RelayCommand canExecute parameter is `Func<T,bool>` it means that you pass method with the same signature (like below). For more information about `Func<T,TResult>` see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 RelayCommand m_PrintAllChartsCommand;
 public ICommand PrintAllChartsCommand
 {
       get
       {
             return m_PrintAllChartsCommand ?? (m_PrintAllChartsCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(
                        OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView,
                        IsPrintAndExportEnabled
                        ));
        }
  }

 private void OnPrintAllChartsInCurrentView(object arg)
 {

 }

 private bool IsPrintAndExportEnabled(object arg)
 {
      return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me (IsRealShunter is a boolean property):

```
RaiseAlarmClickCommand = new RelayCommand<Guid>(RaiseAlarmClick, x => IsRealShunter);
```

RaiseAlarmClick is a method:

```
private void RaiseAlarmClick(Guid idPrinter) {...}
```

One small note, if something gets updated in your view model and you want to make sure your RelayCommand reflects the changes, call this from where the change occured:

```
RaiseAlarmClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```